# Firefox bug with CSS transition in combination with transform and background-color

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

we have a weird bug with a css transition in combination with `transform: translate` and changing a background-color. The HTML structure is a sidebar on the left side which is fixed. Within this sidebar is a container with text. Based on the y-scroll position i change the background-color of the sidebar and the y-position of the textcontainer with translate. Both elements have the CSS transition property to have a smooth animation. As you can see in the following gif it worked not quiet well. The textcontainer gets the background-color of the sidebar for about a half second.

[image: Bug illustration]

For better understanding here is also a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0cgzpnkz/). Does someone knows a similiar problem like mine?

Comment: I don't see that at all (in Firefox).

Comment: Can you add what version of FF you're testing on? I just tried your fiddle on v41.0.2 and it works fine.

Comment: I have check this one in Firefox 42.0 and everything works fine, what is your Firefox version ?

Comment: Firefox Version 42.0

Comment: It's not impossible that this is an issue with lower-level code (video drivers). Do you have other (different) devices to test on?

Comment: You're right @Pointy video driver problem

Comment: happens for me as well, see here: http://imgur.com/3CNIwmi
Testen on Firefox 42 on Mac 10.11